# VBA Offset Cell in left direct

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to transform my report into this form shown in the picture !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So4Aq.png)

I've tried to use Offset function or dynamic assigning, but when I used to try these methods , the first row of my report was deleted.
Here is the code

```
Sub create_report()

Dim itemWs As Worksheet, offerWs As Worksheet, testWs As Worksheet
Dim itemLastRow As Long, offerLastRow As Long
Dim offerLastCol As Long, itemLastCol As Long
Dim dataRng As Range

Set itemWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("nn_rfx_compare_per_lot")

Set offerWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Offers")

Set testWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testowy")

itemLastRow = itemWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
offerLastRow = offerWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

offerLastCol = offerWs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
itemLastCol = itemWs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set dataRng = testWs.Range("I3:AF" & 4)


'For x = 2 To 7
    'On Error Resume Next
    'itemWs.Range("I" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(itemWs.Range("C" & x).Value & itemWs.Range("B" & x).Value, dataRng, 3, 0)
'Next x



Sheets("Testowy").Range(Sheets("Testowy").Cells(offerLastCol - 1, 1), Sheets("Testowy").Cells(itemLastRow + 4, itemLastCol)) = _
Sheets("nn_rfx_compare_per_lot").Range(Sheets("nn_rfx_compare_per_lot").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("nn_rfx_compare_per_lot").Cells(itemLastRow, itemLastCol)).Value

Sheets("Testowy").Range(Sheets("Testowy").Cells(1, itemLastCol + 1), Sheets("Testowy").Cells(offerLastCol - 1, offerLastRow + itemLastCol)) = _
WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("Offers").Range(Sheets("Offers").Cells(1, 2), Sheets("Offers").Cells(offerLastRow, offerLastCol)))

Dim lastTestCol As Long
lastTestCol = testWs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim ColumnLetter As String

For Row = 6 To 11

    For Col = 9 To lastTestCol
    On Error Resume Next
        testWs.Cells(Row, Col).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(testWs.Cells( _
        5, Col), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(testWs.Cells(Row, 3).Value, testWs.Cells(3, Col), 0))
        
        
    Next Col
    
    
    

Next Row

For Cl = 9 To lastTestCol
    On Error Resume Next
    testWs.Cells(5, Cl) = ""
Next Cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you describe with more detail what you are trying to accomplish? The picture was helpful but not enough to understand the goal.

Comment: The goal is to merge values which transposed item_id correaleates with item_id in Range(C6:C11) and which prop_id is  and which prop_id is the same as the next one. I have updated image, how it should look like ;D

Comment: Using `On Error Resume Next` will hide your errors.  It is useful at times, but you should reset to `On Error Goto 0`.  In your case it doesn't appear necessary.